# Shopping Cart Rule - exclude items already on sale?

Tags: magento-1.7, sales, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm trying to apply a rule to app products in a couple categories, except for those that are currently on sale.

In this example: sale runs from 3/26/14 to 3/31/14

Under Actions, I've got it to apply when:

```
If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :
   -Category is one of 9, 10, 11      //These are the products affected by the rule.
   -If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE :
      -Special Price From Date equals or greater than 2014-04-01 
      -Special Price To Date equals or less than 2014-03-25
      -If ALL of these conditions are FALSE :
        -Special Price equals or greater than 0.01
```

The latter part says:

- The "special price to date" is the day before the cart rule begins. So if it was on sale, it's checking to make sure that sale has expired.
- The "special price from date" is the day after cart rule ends. So the rule applies to things that will be on sale in the future, but aren't yet.
- The 'special price' at the end, checks to see if the special price field is blank. If it's blank, the item isn't/wasn't/won't-be on sale.

So why is my rule applying to items that it shouldn't?

Extra info: There are some items that have a special price start date but no end date, and some that have both start & end dates. But it seems to be applying to all of them equally.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to apply the rule where the product is *not* in a particular category.

Put all of your items on sale into that category. This can be further automated at a later stage by populating the category dynamically in a scheduled job.

Comment: Either that, or create a specific attribute called "Is On Sale" and exclude all products set to "Yes" from the promo rules.

Comment: No offense intended, but I'm not sure I'm in love with this particular method, as it's definitely a workaround. And my method _should_ work. At any rate, is the sale category a relatively standard way for other stores? I've got a sale page already, but it doesn't create a category to do so.

Comment: The sale "page" can be hidden as a non-visible category ... we usually recommend this as the way of handling it because it's easy for admins to bulk add/remove products from the category rather than having to edit the special price and from/to date.